# Python: subprocess.Popen store output in a list of list

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running sql query in a shell script which I am running inside Python script. As, in prod env I dont have cx_Oracle library so I need to use shell script. Now when I invoke shell script using python, I am getting output as string. How can I convert this output into a list. You can use  commands.getoutput or subprocess.Popen only.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re,os,commands,os.path
import subprocess

#output = commands.getoutput("sh FA_FMW.sh")
output = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "ABC.sh"],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print output
```

Output:

```
Successfully created: APPABC.env
ABCenv succeeded.

ABC_ACTIVITIES              ACTIVITIES
12.11.1.8.0                     VALID       N

ABC_BIA_CLOUD               ATBCITE
12.11.1.8.1                     VALID       Y
```

above I just mentioned two rows of query output which have 5 columns. How can I access this output row and column wise so that I perform certain operation on version number and valid invalid flags. Also, need to filter first two lines of success message. For example I need to print only first two columns of each row. Here two lines are part of same row.

```
for i in range(0, len(output)):
        print output[i][0], output[i][2], output[i][4]
```

output:

```
ABC_ACTIVITIES 12.11.1.8.0 N
ABC_ACTIVITIES 12.11.1.8.1 Y
```

Comment: Can you post expected output to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
output = """Successfully created: APPABC.env
ABCenv succeeded.

ABC_ACTIVITIES              ACTIVITIES
12.11.1.8.0                     VALID       N

ABC_BIA_CLOUD               ATBCITE
12.11.1.8.1                     VALID       Y"""

for chunk in re.findall(r"\n\b[A-Z_]+\b.*?\b[A-Z]\b", output, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print chunk.split()[0::2]
```

**Output:**

```
['ABC_ACTIVITIES', '12.11.1.8.0', 'N']
['ABC_BIA_CLOUD', '12.11.1.8.1', 'Y']
```

Comment: thanks Rakesh, few issues, there some extra lines in the starting (as mentioned in the question) and end which need to be removed also in between queries result sometimes there is one empty line or 2 empty lines.

Comment: Updated ans. Please check.